# Python: how to save the output to a text file?

Tags: python, save, output

1.
    I tried with -o 
 werwe wer wer wer we
2.and >>text.txtrr
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

```
    # -*- coding: iso-8859-15
    import sys
    import requests
    import os
    if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
            os.system('clear') 
            print "Please wait.."`enter code here`
            P1 = str(sys.argv[1])
            url = "http://example.com/index.php"
            data= {
               'getp1':'%s'%(P1)
            }
            r = requests.get(url,params=data) -o text.txt
            os.system('clear')
            print r.content 

    else:
            print "[ERROR] Este programa nerrcesita un parámetro";
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this isn't a well-put question.  You don't state what your error is, or what you expected to happen.  But, there are some obvious things in your code that we can fix.

You seem to be mixing up shell commands and python code, after you've taken in sys.argv.

```
r = requests.get(url,params=data) -o text.txt
```

Is not valid python code - it looks like you're trying to use commandline syntax there.

I would suggest something like:

```
r = requests.get(url,params=data) 
f = open('text.txt', 'w' )
f.write(r.content)
f.close()
```

It's also worth noting that given you're downloading a PHP file contents, you probably want the r.text function, rather than r.content, [which is for non-text responses (like images).  you should also set the encoding.](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content)